# On Amazon AWS services, is there a way to get Heroku-like managed EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, package, instance, managed

Is there a way to get Heroku-like managed EC2 instance on AWS where upgrading to the latest system packages are done for me?  Basically, I can still get a root-shell if I want, but otherwise, all the packages I needed for say running a Python web stack would all be automatically upgraded to the latest stable combination for me.

Does AWS currently offer such a service natively?  I know I can use a 3rd party service provider that wraps around EC2 but I am specifically asking for the native support by AWS.

Answer (score 0):

[Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) is AWS's answer to Heroku.  It provides a simple command-line interface as well as a UI, through AWS's Management Console, for creating and updating applications.  It also handles all the instance OS updates for you when you launch a new environment.

There is no additional charge for using Elastic Beanstalk. You just pay the normal AWS usage charges.